# Is there any difference between USB-C and USB 3.1

Tags: usb-3, usb-c, usb-3.1-type-c

I have been hearing a bit about this new USB-C standard, but is it the same as USB 3.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Is there any difference between USB-C and USB 3.1?

The new USB type C specification is version 1.0.

USB C **replaces** multiple type-B and type-A connectors and cables.

> The USB 3.1 standard is backward compatible with USB 3.0 and USB 2.0.
>
> **The USB Type-C Specification 1.0 defines a new small reversible-plug
>   connector for USB 3.1 devices.** The type-C plug will be used at both
>   host and device side, replacing multiple type-B and type-A connectors
>   and cables with a future-proof standard similar to Apple Lightning and
>   Thunderbolt.

Source [USB 3.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_3.1)

---

#### Further reading

- [USB Type-C Specification Release 1.0](https://archive.org/stream/pdfy-b57BTnAHh_rUeXBf/USB%20Type-C%20Specification%20Release%201.0_djvu.txt)